en vbnt y opnxml color fondo celdas excel
Intento aplicar un color de fondo a celdas de excel y no lo hace
Dim fill2 As New Spreadsheet.Fill()
Dim patternFill2 As New Spreadsheet.PatternFill()
patternFill1.PatternType = Spreadsheet.PatternValues.Solid
Dim fgColor As New Spreadsheet.ForegroundColor()
fgColor.Rgb = "B2A1C7"
patternFill2.ForegroundColor = fgColor
fill2.PatternFill = patternFill2
fills.Append(fill2)

No me aplica el color de fondo
